# Disjunctive normal form process

Tags: propositional-calculus, disjunctive-normal-form

Say I want to transform a term in to disjunctive normal form; $$((\neg p \land \neg r) \lor q) \land ( \neg r \lor p)$$

Then what is the next step? I keep going round in circles. Do I do $$((\neg r \land ((\neg p \land \neg r) \lor q) \lor (p \land ((\neg p \land \neg r) \lor q))?$$

Comment: For small formulas, you can also just write the truth table and then write the DNF or CNF directly from there. This is impractical if there are many variables, but it can be easier than doing many transformations when there are few variables.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that would be good: just keep distributing any $\land $ over $\lor$ and you'll get there. In fact, you're just two such distributions away from it being in DNF

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Temporarily substituting $x$ for $(\neg p\land\neg r)$ will make things less cluttered.
$$\begin{split}((\neg p \land \neg r) \lor q) &\land ( \neg r \lor p)\\(x\lor q)&\land(\neg r\lor p)&\quad&\text{substitution: }[x\backslash(\neg p\land\neg r)]\\ ((x\lor q)\land \neg r)~&\lor~((x \lor q)\land p) &&\text{distribution }\land\text{ over }\lor \end{split}$$ This is where you are.   Can you now see how to distribute within those two disjuncts to get a disjunctive series of conjunctions?   Well, after that, substitute back and you shall see what you must do then.